# Remove a single node on a click on the button

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I am trying to create a function where I can delete a "Restaurant Name" based on the input from the user in the "TextField" after clicking the submit button.

The Restaurants are categorized into Breakfast, lunch and dinner.

I tried using `remove()` function but it deletes *everything* from Breakfast, Name to all my data within.

```js
{
 "BibleVerse": "Verse1",
 "Breakfast": {
  "Name": {
   "-JyjnX_b6yQCR068oA9i": "firefly",
   "-Jyjn_5Wzr1vP5rXi_IG": "congee queen",
   "-JyjncESMv5vd2nQh4l6": "steakhouse"
  }
 },
 "Dinner": "Dinner",
 "Gathering": "Home",
 "Lunch": "Lunch",
 "NexcellMember": "Member1",
 "User": "Adrian"
}
```

Here is my Java class, which at the moment... I don't know how to use the text captured from `Textfield` to set it to delete from Firebase, I can only delete the entire dataset.

```java
public class DeleteRestaurant extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deleterestaurant);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Button DelRestNow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delbutton);
        DelRestNow.setOnClickListener(Handler);
    }

    //Specific Button - Delete Restaurant Name
    View.OnClickListener Handler = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            DelData();
        }
    };

    public void DelData(){
        // GET and DELETE(Through Database Restaurant Name
        EditText mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.delText);
        String RestName = mEdit.getText().toString();
        // Get from Database
        Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myfburl.firebaseio.com");
        ref.child("Breakfast/Name").removeValue();
        mEdit.setText("");
    }

}
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, thanks for spending time to help me again. I have included my java class in the question. Please have a look, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Better, thanks for that. I'll delete my comment to clean up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a query to find the item you want. In this case, since you're looking for items whose **value** matches the string the user enters, you'll want to use `orderByValue()`:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.delText);
final String name = edit.getText().toString();
Query query = mRef.child("Breakfast/Name").orderByValue().equalTo(name);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            itemSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
edit.setText("");
```

I've added an activity that shows this in action to my demo app: https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android